# Using node.js worker threads with Meteor apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to use worker threads in my Meteor app to offload CPU intensive tasks. I'm using the @arrows/worker library instead of the worker_threads module directly. I tried some very simple test code (below), but got the following error.

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ReferenceError: meteorInstall is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (meteor://app/app/app.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (internal/main/worker_thread.js:162:24)
    at MessagePort.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at MessagePort.onmessage (internal/worker/io.js:78:8)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at Worker.[kOnErrorMessage] (internal/worker.js:204:10)
    at Worker.[kOnMessage] (internal/worker.js:214:37)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (internal/worker.js:141:57)
    at MessagePort.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at MessagePort.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at MessagePort.onmessage (internal/worker/io.js:78:8)
```

Test code:

```
import worker from '@arrows/worker';

const fn = function (data) {
  console.log('fn');
  return 'abc';
};

const asyncFn = worker(fn);

const runIt = async () => {
  console.log('a');
  try {
    const out = await asyncFn('a');
    console.log('b', out);
  }
  catch (err) { console.log(err); }
}

runIt();
```

Comment: Since `@arrows/workers` is a neat wrapper around node's `worker_threads` I am curious if someone get's the native `worker_threads` running with Meteor. It seems, that this is related to the `Worker` thread being tied to a "file" that is loaded different from how the Meteor app loads, rather than code in the RAM.

Comment: Relevant feature request in the `meteor/meteor` repo: https://github.com/meteor/meteor-feature-requests/issues/386. Since it is still open I would assume that this is not currently possible or at least that there is no easy way of getting this to work just yet.